# How to use the XSLT Utilities

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

I am a Symphony CMS noob, but this simple problem has been bugging me for hours. How do you actually apply the XSLT utility? For example, I have a utility that I want to apply here: http://www.getsymphony.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/20574/

So I have included this in my page template

```
<xsl:include href="../utilities/misc/email_obfuscator.xsl"/>
```

I have an email address that I want to obfuscate here:

```
<xsl:value-of select="email"/>
```

I know I have to 'call' the 'obfuscate-email' utility but not sure how to do that. Can anyone point me the correct way?

How about when the utility accepts more than one parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call your named template, you just have to use the following code inside your XSLT:

```
<xsl:call-template name="obfuscate-email">
 <xsl:with-param name="email" select="$email"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Where the variable `$email` contains the value of the mail. You can change that with any valid XPath expression.

Then if you have several parameters defined in your named template, you just have to add other `<xsl:with-param/>` elements.